# Cannot reference class from another class in same package

Tags: android, scala, android-studio

I'm admittedly new to Scala and Android programming and in all my searching I haven't been able to find answer to help me understand and resolve my problem.

Here's a gist of my two scala classes https://gist.github.com/Daikamar/f15288a7bf732cd5b55c

I'm running through the tutorial found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

which I'm trying to adapt to scala code (I have need for understanding Scala for work and a personal desire to mess around with Android development so I figured I'd try and combine these efforts).

The problem is seen in DisplayMessageActivity.scala in which the IDE reports that it cannot resolve MyActivity in this line:

```
val message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.ExtraMessage)
```

I feel like this should work. I can get it to resolve if I change MyActivity to an object, but then that breaks other pieces of the application that expects MyActivity to be a class.

An help in getting me to understand my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You can not do `MyActivity.ExtraMessage`, there is no `static` in scala. You may need to follow companion pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference the `ExtraMessage` field from `MyActivity` as though it was a 'static' field (in Java terminology). To access `ExtraMessage` in your other activity you will need to either obtain an instance of `MyActivity` that you can then de-reference, or add a companion object (defined using the `object` keyword in the same file in which the class is defined) for `MyActivity` and define the field there:

```
object MyActivity {
  val ExtraMessage = "net.daikamar.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

  // any other 'static' declarations
}

class MyActivity() extends ...
```

then your call as above will work.

Comment: That did it thanks! I also had to change MyActivity class in MyActivity.scala from:
intent.putExtra(ExtraMessage, message)
to
intent.putExtra(MyActivity.ExtraMessage, message)

Comment: You can avoid that, if you wish, by adding `import MyActivity.ExtraMessage`, or `import MyActivity._` (typically the latter, as one of the first lines after the declaration of your `DisplayMessageActivity` class).